# Delphi SOAP Request

Tags: web-services, delphi, soap

I'm trying to send a SOAP Request to a webservice in Delphi XE5. Actually there is a WSDL available which I imported via WSDL Importer. I established a connection to this webservice with the components THTTPRIO (rio) and IdEncoderMIME1 for the HTTP Authentication Request.

The SOAP Request was build via TXMLDocument and has the following structure:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:cod=NS_Codelist>
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <cod:GetLatestChangeDatesRequest>
         <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         <CodeListID>1035</CodeListID>
      </cod:GetLatestChangeDatesRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Furthermore I received the Porttype of the webservice.

```
codeserv:= GetCodeListPortType(true,'',rio);
```

These are methods from the WSDL:

```
codeserv.GetLatestChangeDates(const body:GetLatestChangeDatesRequestType):GetLatestChangeDatesResponseType

GetLatestChangeDatesRequestType = array of Int64;  
GetLatestChangeDatesRequest = GetLatestChangeDatesRequestType;

GetLatestChangeDatesResponseType = array of CodeListLatestChangeDateType;   
GetLatestChangeDatesResponse = GetLatestChangeDatesResponseType;

CodeListLatestChangeDateType 
property CodeListID: Int64
property LatestChangeDate: TXSDate
```

I have already tried to set an array of Int64 for the parameter but then it says "element CodeListID is missing".

Unfortunately I don't find a way to send this XML SOAP Request to the webservice and to receive the response. Any ideas?

EDIT: I have tried to use the WSDL methods

```
var
    codeserv: CodeListPortType;
    arrIDs: GetLatestChangeDatesRequest;
    response: GetLatestChangeDatesResponse;

   begin
    codeserv:= GetCodeListPortType(true,'',rio);
    SetLength(arrIDs,1);
    arrIDs[0]:= 1035;
    response:= codeserv.GetLatestChangeDates(arrIDs);
```

But then I receive the following error message: 'invalid content was found starting with element 'long'. One of '{CodeListID}' is expected.'
In the SOAP Request there have to be the element CodeListID. Unfortunately it seems the method GetLatestChangeDates isn't creating the elements in the SOAP Request. The SOAP Request posted above should have been created with this method (hopefully).

Comment: Why are You even using TXMLDocument if You allready imported WSDL ? What is actual code You used ?

Comment: I think the TXMLDoument isn't necessary but I have no clue how to send a request with the WSDL. In the past I worked with many WSDL imports but it was always possible to request the data by calling the right method with the right parameters. But here you have to create a SOAP request and I don't know how to do this in Delphi. Actually I think I have to use the methods ObjectToSOAP or SOAPToObject but how?